# puppet ruby wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby, puppet

First off, I know there are a lot of questions regarding this error and I have checked them all, mine is not solved using any of their solutions however.

I am working for the first time with Puppet / Ruby and am having the following issue.

I created this function:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:phpversion, :type => :rvalue) do
        %x["/usr/bin/php -r 'echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . \".\" . PHP_MINOR_VERSION;'"]
    end
end
```

And when I call it in my manifest file using:

```
$phpversion = phpversion()
```

It throws, when I execute the agent, the error "`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/x/manifests/somefile.pp:123 on node foo.example.bar"`

I tried adding `|args|` after the `do` statement and removing `:type` but it keeps throwing the same error. when I use `$phpversion = phpversion` it just thinks its a text string instead of a function (which I expected, but tried anyway).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that this function will find the puppet master's php version, not the version on the node being configured?

Comment: At the time I wasn't and got pointed towards it by a colleague, thanks for the information though as I would've continued thinking it would've been the client's version. 

Either way I'm still quite curious as to how to solve this issue so I can prevent/fix it in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get the version of php, it'd probably be easier to do it as a fact:

```
Facter.add(:phpversion) do
  setcode do
    if Facter::Util::Resolution.which('php')
      Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('/usr/bin/php -r 'echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . \".\" . PHP_MINOR_VERSION;'"').lines.first.split(/"/)[1].strip
    end
  end
end
```

Put this a directory `lib/facter/` in your module, then reference it in your manifest as `$::phpversion`

Comment: Looks like the quotes in the exec need to be escaped.